# What is wrong with this MATLAB code? Vectorizing a For-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, indexing

I want to compute the sum of `1/((1^2)(3^2))+ 1/((3^2)(5^2))+1/((5^2)(7^2))+ ...`

The following code is my attempt at computing that sum with no looping:

```
n = 1000;
t0 = clock;    %vectorizing we get 
x1 = (1./(1:2:n)).^2;
y1 = (1/(3:2:n)).^2y1.*x1;
t = sum(y1.*x1)etime(clock,t0)
```

But MATLAB gives an error that the vector sizes do not agree.

How can I fix this to get the correct answer?

Comment: I see that someone already provided the answer for the specific case, but given the error message I would have suggested you to check the size of all vectors and see which one is not what you expected.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
y1=(1/(3:2:n)).^2y1.*x1;
```

should be:

```
y1=(1/(3:2:n+2)).^2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I am new here :), let me check ;)

Comment: no problem, if it works out then select my answer so other people can benefit from it!

Comment: anytime, this is what the website is for!